# Displaying Data in Django using HighCharts

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, django, highcharts

I have text data in a example.txt file in the following format

```
[[Date.UTC(1970, 10, 25), 0],
 [Date.UTC(1970, 11,  6), 0.25],
 [Date.UTC(1970, 11, 20), 1.41],
 [Date.UTC(1970, 11, 25), 1.64],
 [Date.UTC(1971, 0,  4), 1.6]]
```

Which I am reading in django view.py file as follows

```
filepath = os.getcwd()
f = open(filepath+"/main/static/main/data/example.txt", "r")
dataset = f.read()

def home(request):
    context = {'dataset': dataset}
    return render(request, 'main/home.html', context)
```

Loading it in the template as follows

```
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<div id='dataset' data-dataset={{ dataset }} style="width:100%; height:500px;"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'main/js/main.js' %}" ></script>
```

And javascript main.js file with highchart code as follows

```
const app_control = (function() {
    var sdata;
    var init_charts;

    /*
    VARIABLES INITIALIZATIONS
    */

    /*
    DEFINE THE FUNCTIONS
    */  
    

    /*
    Initialize Functions
    */
    init_charts = function(sdata){
        const chart = Highcharts.chart('container', {
            chart: {
                type: 'spline'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Example Data from '
            },
            xAxis: {
                type: "datetime",
                title: {
                    text: 'Date'
                }
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'Data in Y Axis'
                }
            },
            colors: ['#06C'],
            series: [{
                name:'Visualized Data',
                data: sdata
            }]
        })
    }

    /*
    PUBLIC INTERFACE
    */
    public_interface = {};

    /*
    RUN THE FUNCTIONS
    */
    $(function(){
        sdata = $('#TimeSeries').data('dataset');
        init_charts(sdata);
    });
    return public_interface;
}());
```

The question is, why is the data not visualizing? If you do console.log(sdata); you see the data, but it is not loading in HighCharts. What could be the reason for this behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is possible, you should change the data format in your file from `Date.UTC(1970, 10, 25)` to for example: `25660800000` (timestamp in milliseconds).

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/t2rde3bk/

---

If you need to keep the current format, you can:

- use eval -> `data: eval(sdata)` - definitely not recommended

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/z45anjo7/

---

- write a custom parser

---

```
const rows = sdata.split('Date.UTC(').slice(1);
const parsedData = [];

rows.forEach(row => {
  const splitted = row.split('),');
  const date = splitted[0];
  const y = splitted[1].split(']')[0];

  parsedData.push([
    Date.UTC(...date.split(',')),
    +y
  ]);
});

const chart = Highcharts.chart('container', {
  ...,
  series: [{
    data: parsedData
  }]
})
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/voe4q9bf/

Comment: Am going to mark this as the correct answer to my question since it has worked for me. Follow up questions if you don't mind, 
1. While dealing with local files in Django that need to be visualized, what efficient way would you recommend I go about it?
2. Why is the eval() option in the question above not recommended
3. Why was the code above not working in the first place?
I do appreciate your answer a lot.

Comment: 1. I definitely recommend you to use the timestamp format. 2. Please check this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86513/why-is-using-the-javascript-eval-function-a-bad-idea 3. The code was not working because your data was a string and it needs to be an array.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Would you clarify more on question 1 kindly. E.g I would store the files in this manner, then load them in here, and visualize them this way. Probably that the recommendation I would need.

Comment: I am not a backend expert, but I would start with the proper data format (timestamp, y value) and find a different way to pass the data to Highcharts, maybe by using JSON?

Answer (score 0):

Because most probably the data is treated as string and not as a list of list or JSON list, check the types of the dataset in the charts function and you can JSON.parse to load the json from a string

Comment: How would you solve this issue?

Comment: What is the type of dataset? You can use JSON.parse in JS side

Comment: Highcharts wants it in the same format as in the text file, if you do typeof sdata you get object

Comment: Then base the value of sdata.dataset as highcharts needs an array not object

Comment: Apologies, I answered you based on what I had done a while ago.  Typeof is sdata is string and not object. If you use JSON.parse it doesn;t work. sdata.dataset is undefined

Comment: Please add sdata as a string to your question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242138/discussion-between-kimlotte-and-mohamed-elkalioby).